# codeigniter $this->email_send-> is not being called

Tags: php, codeigniter

In one of my controller class I have added

```
$this->load->library('session','cart','email_send');
```

The coding part is below:

```
var_dump($optionalInfo); // upto this working fine
$this->email_send->activation_link($optionalInfo); // $optionalInfo is an array containing some data
```

In **email_send class** , **activation_link function** -> I have printed $optionalInfo in first line - but not getting anything.

The email_send class and activation_link function both are ok as ,the same function is working fine when called from another conrtroller class .

What can be the issue? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Load your libraries like this..

```
$this->load->library(array('session','cart','email_send'));
```

For **loading multiple libraries:**

```
$this->load->library(array('library_name1','library_name2',..));
```

Comment: glad to help you.